# iOS 7 UIImagePickerController with Overlay - retake and use photo not usable

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

Even though I set userInteractionsEnabled to NO and my overlayframe is cleary not overlapping the buttons, I cannot click them.

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
    // Init Picker
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    //Create camera overlay for square pictures
    CGFloat navigationBarHeight = picker.navigationBar.bounds.size.height + 25;
    CGFloat height = picker.view.bounds.size.height - 2 * navigationBarHeight;
    CGFloat width = picker.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, navigationBarHeight, width, height);
    CGFloat barHeight = (f.size.height - f.size.width) / 2;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size);
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7] set];
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, 0, f.size.width, barHeight), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, f.size.height - barHeight, f.size.width, barHeight - 4), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    UIImage *overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageView *overlayIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:f];

    // Disable all user interaction on overlay
    [overlayIV setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [overlayIV setExclusiveTouch:NO];
    [overlayIV setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];

    // Map generated image to overlay
    overlayIV.image = overlayImage;

    // Present Picker
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
        picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }
    [picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayIV];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You set userInteractionsEnabled to NO for the buttons? That would be wrong. Another idea is that your buttons' frames are too small. That will draw the buttons but they won't be touchable.

Comment: where have you set the userInteractionEnabled in button or the whole view. In both the cases it won't work. As first you might have the idea and second if view is not accessible then how a subview of a view would be accesssed

Comment: I added the code above. As you can see, I only set setUserInteractionEnabled to the overlay. The buttons are from the stock UIImagePickerController served by iOS. They work if I dont use an overlay.

Comment: Solved! 

I had to change:

`[picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayIV];`

to:

`picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayIV;`

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this: `[picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayIV];`

to: `[picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayIV];`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but my solution was slightly different. i was using xib files and the appropriate views and buttons were indeed in the correct hierarchy.

but i had to dynamically create a temporary view after the main parent view loaded (viewDidLoad) and add this temp view as the camera overlay. then i added the buttons as a subview to this temp view.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   ImgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 

   if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    // note: need to set a manually created view (vOverlay) as the image picker overlay,
    //  and then add the button controls (vControls) to this manually created vOverlay.
    //  Otherwise, the buttons in vControls are not clickable
     UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:ImgPicker.view.frame];
     [tempView addSubview:self.vButtons];

     ImgPicker.cameraOverlayView = tempView;
    }
 }
```